# HorizontalScrollView strange behaviour

Tags: android, scrollview

I'm trying to create a HorizontalScrollView which holds a LinearLayout inside , which then holds a bunch of small ImageButton's acting as "items" or "products" to scroll through. Issue is that you can scroll another "length" of the scrollview once you've reached the final item in the LinearLayout.

```
<HorizontalScrollView
            android:id="@+id/productScroll"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:measureAllChildren="false"
            android:scrollbars="none"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

        <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:background="@drawable/textfield_bg">

            <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/item1"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/item1"
                    android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                    android:onClick="useItem1"/>

            <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/item2"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/item2"
                    android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
                    android:onClick="useItem2"/>

            <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/item3"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/item3"
                    android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
                    android:onClick="useItem3"/>

            <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/item4"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/item4"
                    android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
                    android:onClick="useItem4"/>

            <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/item5"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/item5"
                    android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
                    android:onClick="useItem5"/>
        </LinearLayout>

    </HorizontalScrollView>
```

So it holds 5 items, once I reach the final one by scrolling, I can continue scrolling alot of blank space. But here come's the thing, it holds 5 items på default when the activity is started but in that activity they can choose another "set" of items to appear in the scrollview, which will hold 12 items. So what I'm looking for is a ScrollView that adapt's it's horizontal lenght to the number of item that nests in the LinearLayout, if possible.

Nevertheless I would like to fix the blank space.

Comment: Why do you use `layout_marginStart` and `layout_marginLeft` in the same `ImageButton` ? Does `40dp` gap considered as "a lot of blank space" ? Plus, avoid using each `onClick` on each `ImageButton`. Use `tag` to identify the button clicked and use a single function to handle all the clicks.

Comment: The IDEA recommended using marginStart with marginLeft for better "left to right" structure or something. No 40dp is just the space between objects. The length of all 5 "items" is added after scrolling through them, so twice as long as it should be.

Comment: Yes, just leave the Start parameter will be fine. No need to duplicate it.